# Reading request headers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dns

I need to be able to read the request headers coming from a redirect from a naked domain:

```
http://mydomain.com
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.html
```

I need `index.html` to be able to parse any original request `path` and `queries`, how can I do that?

E.g

From naked domain: `http://mydomain.com/abc` to `http://www.mydomain.com/index.html` and then  index.html will get the `abc` path request.

The question is how to be able to achieve this?

**A similar question:** [Using DNS to redirect to another URL with a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444055/using-dns-to-redirect-to-another-url-with-a-path)

Comment: How are you doing this redirect?  Or is that what you are trying to ask?

Comment: In simple terms what I need to do is for the DNS host to forward with path, either as real path or just a HTTP header in the request.

Comment: Why not perform the redirection on the server-side?

Comment: I'd suggest using your webserver to do this.  Apache's `mod_rewrite` is perfect for this job.  (P.S. Your "similar question" shows that using DNS for this is *impossible*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use document properties to check and reditect
for others questions use navigator  roperties

Get referrer use = **document.referrer** or **document.URL**

Look : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

In apache the best solution is control that with .httaccess