# IIS Rewrite Rule: Redirect old domain to specific page in new domain

Tags: asp.net, redirect, dns, url-rewriting

We have a requirement where we need to redirect the old domain to specific page in new domain.

e.g.

```
GIVEN I navigate to http://old.domain.com
THEN I should be redirected to http://new.domain.com/apple

GIVEN I navigate to http://veryold.domain.com
THEN I should be redirected to http://new.domain.com/apple
```

I had a look at link below which suggest it's not possible with DNS redirect:
[Using DNS to redirect to another URL with a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444055/using-dns-to-redirect-to-another-url-with-a-path)

I'm not really good on IIS Rewrite rules.

Can someone please help?

I've started with below which doesn't seem to be working well:

```
<rule name="Redirect old domain to new domain page" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^old.domain.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://new.domain.com/apple" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```