# How do I add a DNS record that redirects a certain URL path to another URL path while masked?

Tags: redirect, dns

I want to go from http://example.com/whatever to http://blah.com/stuff while displaying http://example.com/whatever using only DNS records on the domain name provider. (I use Namecheap.)

I realize there is a situation like this. Namely, [Using DNS to redirect to another URL with a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444055/using-dns-to-redirect-to-another-url-with-a-path/) . Another idea I had would be http://something.example.com/ to redirect to http://blah.com/stuff WHILE displaying http://something.example.com/ .

If these examples aren't helping, I need it to redirect from one URL path (or CNAME, as in example 2) to another URL path while displaying the original path/CNAME (like a URL Frame but for paths).

Any help, please?

Comment: Well do you have access to the code on http://example.com/whatever like is it your website?

Comment: Also does it actually need to redirect?

Comment: 1.) It is indeed my website. I bought it from Namecheap and have access to it from the Namecheap dashboard. I'm able to add any type of DNS records I need.

2.) What do you mean? It needs to redirect but still display as if it hadn't (like a URL Frame).

Comment: You cannot do redirects with DNS. Also DNS and web server configuration isn't programming so it's belongs to Server Fault