# best way to redirect domain purchased in azure to external site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, redirect, domain-name

I purchased a domain in the Azure Portal and I would like to redirect it to a section on another site.

For example, Say I purchased domain1.com in azure portal, i would then like to redirect that to http://www.anotherdomain.com/subsection.

Is this possible, and if so, what is the best way to do it?

Many Thanks,

JJ

Comment: Yes, it seems that the Alias doesn't support this format url.

Comment: Im thinking the best/easiest way is going to be to set up an app service linked to my domains and forward them using basic meta tags? Thoughts?

Comment: see if this helps - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32229.azure-create-an-url-rewrite-azure-web-app.aspx

Comment: @Jolly From this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444055/using-dns-to-redirect-to-another-url-with-a-path), we know the DNS won't redirect the path portion of a URL. And in this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) about DNS, we could know the Domain name syntax doesn't support '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Advanced Management portal, you can set up forwarding to achieve this scenario.
In your azure portal, navigate to your App Service Domain

1. Under "Domain Management", select Advanced Management Portal.
2. In the Advanced Management Portal, Select the DNS tab.
3. In the "Forwarding" section, add your desired "http://www.anotherdomain.com/subsection"
4. Save your changes.