# How can I use DNS to point sub.site.com to site.com without affecting sub.site.com/page-1?

Tags: dns, redirect

I have a self-hosted WordPress website (site.com) that I'm trying to integrate with a 3rd party's white-labeled WordPress website to give the appearance of one website. The white-labeled site is mapped to a subdomain (sub.site.com).

The sites are styled almost identically and I've replicated the menus across both sites with some links pointing to pages on site.com and others pointing to pages on sub.site.com as appropriate. The one link the third party won't allow me control over is the Home link on the menu of sub.site.com. As a result, the home link points to a different page depending on which page you're on. I basically have two home pages and I only want one.

Is there a way to use DNS to point sub.site.com to site.com without affecting pages like sub.site.com/page-1 or sub.site.com/page-2? If not, is there a workaround? Keep in mind I don't have access to the server sub.site.com is installed on?

Thanks

Comment: How many pages do you have from sub.site.com and are you going to add more in the future?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using DNS to redirect to another URL with a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444055/using-dns-to-redirect-to-another-url-with-a-path)

Comment: The domain sub.site.com has hundreds of posts (travel deals) that are generated and expired automatically. In addition, it has dozens of static pages (destination guides) and a couple of search pages with embedded booking engines.