# Why do I need to create custom domain in API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am deploying a API gateway to AWS which gives me a random URL and I'd like to configure custom domain. Based on my understanding, I just need to create a CNAME in route53 for the custom domain  point to the api gateway random URL but after some reading, it says I also need to create a custom domain in API gateway. I can make it work but I don't understand why I need that in API gateway. Isn't it just a CNAME which can make it work?

Comment: A `CNAME` is not enough if you want to omit the stage from the URL.

Comment: why CNAME is not enough? Is it just because the stage in url `***/$stage` at the end? If yes, can I add the path in route53 CNAME?

Comment: No, a CNAME cannot point to a path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444055/using-dns-to-redirect-to-another-url-with-a-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behind the scene, API Gateway does 2 things automatically for you when you create a custom domain name, e.g: example.com via its interface

1. It creates a hidden cloudfront distribution with the domain: xyz.cloudfront.net
2. It configures that distribution to allow CNAME from your example.com

What you will have to do manually is to create an alias record in Route53 pointing to xyz.cloudfront.net.

As you notice, you can do all these steps manually through Cloudfront and Route 53 interfaces and it would still work. However, since API Gateway is not aware of this manual configuration, you have to do the mapping (between cloudfront and API Gateway) yourself, instead of point-and-click interface provided by API Gateway interface.

In other words, API Gateway simplifies several Cloudfront configuration steps you have to do otherwise.