# Github Org custom domain

Tags: github, dns, github-pages, cname, namecheap

I have a GitHub pages website and I want redirect it to custom domain. I have added Custom domain in the GitHub pages and A records in the Domain provider and am trying to add CNAME it is not accepting the CNAME: which is https://org-name.github.io/website/

If its a simple repository then I can simply customize the domain by simply pointing it to the CNAME. But Repository Should in the Organization.it is a repository in the GitHub Org and I don't want to create a separate repository.

Comment: I don't get what exactly the problem is, but I can tell: you can't point a CNAME into a path. See this Stack Overflow post for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444055/using-dns-to-redirect-to-another-url-with-a-path

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution
If we point CNAME with org-github.io it will worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).